# How do I get rid of synced contacts?

Tags: contacts, sync, delete

I want to get rid of the contacts that were synced through my Skype, Facebook, and Gmail accounts. How do I do this? I don't want to factory reset my phone, but if I have to....

Answer (score 3):

**Facebook**
Go to settings>Sync Contacts>Remove Facebook data
**Skype**
Settings>Sync contacts>Don't sync
**Gmail**
Not all devices allow to delete gmail contacts from phone, but you can always hide them doing like this.
Open Contacts>Right tap>More options>Display settings>Google>uncheck all groups.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this with contacts from a secondary Google account. I just removed the account and re-added it with contact sync turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Go to gmail on desktop
select contact from the drop down menu by clicking on Gmail on the left top of the screen.
Select all contacts and delete them